# Discharge lithium ion battery to a specific state of charge

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay, lithium-ion, discharge

I am trying to make a circuit to discharge a 4s battery pack to 30% state of charge to ship it safely.

I will be doing this from time to time and would like to discharge the packs rapidly (around an hour at roughly 10A.)

I figured out the no-load voltage which corresponds to that percentage. I was trying to use the pack voltage (divided,) a voltage reference, and a comparator to check for that low voltage and open the switch.

When the battery is discharging the voltage drop across the battery is significant - almost 1V. If I cut the load at that point, the battery immediately floats back up to the no-load voltage, turning the discharge circuit back on and it gets into a weird switching behavior. I've been using a MOSFET but want to switch to a relay so that I don't have to deal with the extra MOSFET heat, just the heat from my load resistors. With a relay, though, I don't want that rapid switching. Is there a good way to prevent the rapid switching behavior?

Comment: Discharge it slower...

Comment: Edited to add that I am trying to discharge them within an hour at 10ish amps

Comment: Add hysteresis to the switching circuit.

Comment: If the cells are fully charged after test, and you know the capacity, and you know the current, divide one by the other and use that number to program a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the battery is discharging the voltage drop across the battery is
> significant,almost 1V. If I cut the load at that point, the battery
> immediately floats back up to the no-load voltage, turning the
> discharge circuit back on

1. Add [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Electronic_circuits) to the comparator circuit, so it doesn't turn back on unless the battery voltage rises more than 1 V.
2. Make the hysteresis so large that the circuit doesn't turn on at all unless you push a button.

The circuit could look like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft8w26.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When voltage falls below the comparator threshold and its output goes low, D2 pulls the + input down to ~0.6 V, forcing the comparator output to stay low even after the battery voltage goes back up. SW1 (when pressed) pulls the - input down below this voltage to start the discharge. The FET is either fully on or fully off so its power dissipation is low.

If the circuit is powered from the battery as shown then SW1 may not be necessary, since when C1 is fully discharged it should cause the comparator to turn on when the battery is plugged in.

Answer (score 4):

A Lithium Ion battery has a very flat discharge curve which makes it difficult to determine the state of charge from voltage. The voltage drop "signal" is swamped by the internal resistance of the battery dropping the voltage as you discharge it. This is probably leading to the behaviour you see. When you stop discharge the voltage comes back up retriggering the discharge circuit.

The only places on the charge discharge curves that you can determine the state of charge by voltage is on the upper and lower "knees" where the voltage changes rapidly with state of charge.

If you are discharging the battery for safe shipping you do not need much accuracy for state of charge. Fully charge the battery as determined by the steep voltage rise at the upper knee and then discharge it by timing the discharge, measure the amps, then multiply amps times hours to burn off 70% of the battery capacity.

Comment: The pack has a gas gauge chip that I read over serial to find the capacity remaining and no-load voltage. I'm just trying to make a "dumb" bench discharger without a computer reading the serial. That's a good idea to fully charge and then use a timer while discharging.

Comment: > the capacity remaining. --- The "State of Charge", not "capacity". The capacity is fixed. What changes is the State of Charger (SoC).

Answer (score 0):

Lithium cells are rated and sold at 3.7V because that is the "storage" voltage that is fairly safe and can last for years. I quickly discharge my 2S (2 cells) battery to about 7V when lighting a car tail light bulb then the unloaded voltage is 3.7V per cell.